# Making text bigger in html without using the big tag N times

Tags: html

I work at a football stadium and my job is to put the scores on the big screen. I need those numbers to come up in a large font so I started learning  HTML5. I need font size 72. (People of my age don't understand this language much. Back when I was in Collage in '65 the only thing we had to know was Fortran/COBOL.)

I don't know the first thing about computers, but I was shocked to find when making the scores bigger on the screen that just putting a `big` tag made the text bigger. So I put 2 `big` tags and much to my astonishment it got even bigger. So if you want to make a text bigger you just have to use the `big` tag.

```
<big>This text gets font size 2</big>

<big><big>This text gets font size 3</big></big>
```

So the more `big` tags you put in there the bigger the text gets. So I put 72 of them. My current code works. I just feel there must be an easier way using html5 alone.

#### Is there an easier way?

```
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
                        Home Score
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>

<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
                             1
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>

<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
                        Away Score
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>

<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
<big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big><big>
                             0
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
</big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big></big>
```

Comment: You need to learn about CSS.

Comment: Woah hold the phone, I'm trying to keep this all in one location, besides the scoreboard doesn't support files.

Comment: You still need to learn about CSS.  (eg, the `<style>` tag and attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style="font-size:72">Score</div>
```

The above will give the text inside the div a font size of 72.

If you want to use the big tag you can do something like this:

```
<big style="font-size:72">Home Score</big>
<big style="font-size:72">1</big>

<big style="font-size:72">Away Score</big>
<big style="font-size:72">2</big>
```

Comment: I don't understand all those symbols how do I do this in HTML5 something like `<TEXTSIZE=72>SCORE</TEXTSIZE>` i don't need any CSS over-complicating my scripts.

Comment: This is HTML5, it's the least complicated way, and there is no scripting here, just tags

Comment: div is just a web element that acts as a container around the text. CSS or Style attributes are by far the most common way to style text in HTML

Comment: you could easily replace `div` with `big` if that's simpler.

Comment: I agree with these guys. The multiple big tags compared to the style attribute with css in it is far less. have you tried h1-h6 tags? you can use the  style attribute as well if you want...

Answer (score 5):

Manipulate the big tag with css

```
    <style>
big {font-size: larger;}
</style>
```

or a desired size like the one you mentioned 72px instead of larger. Make sure to use big tag only once this time.

```
<big>High Score</big>
```

Edit : Or even more simpler way add it like this:

```
<big style="font-size:72px;">High Score</big>
```

Just one big tag ! :)

Comment: So this makes my big tag larger? having a little trouble wrapping my mind around this would you care to elaborate? how much larger are we looking at.

Comment: I like this guys solution, it will atleast cut my script in half. It's simple and it's in english atleast I don't like looking at all these csses divs they all give me a headache.

Comment: You can add the desired font size instead of larger. Just put the css in your style sheet or before </body>

Comment: I did a little bit of digging on the web and it would of been a perfect solution if I could of still used big tags but they increased bigger then normally so that way I would cut down atleast on half of the big tags, it's a shame it only affects one big tag.

Comment: You know what guys I'm just going to stick with the big tags because quite frankly this is giving me a headache.

Comment: Haha I know that frustration of the BIG tags lol ! Okay so here's what you should do, remove those humongous looped in big tags and replace them with simple one big tag preferable the third example I gave you or the first two combined and you are done ! ☻